# Why does my Python code keep repeating itself?

Tags: python

```
class Lust(Scene): # create a class Lust that is-a scene

def enter(self): # create a function named enter
    print "             Virgil leads you on to the second circle of Hell: Lust. \n "
    print "             In this circle, you sees Semiramis, Dido, Cleopatra, "
    print "             Helen of Troy, Achilles, Paris, Tristan, and many others"
    print "             who were overcome by sexual love during their life."
    print "             They are the first ones to be truly punished in Hell. These souls"
    print "             are blown back and forth by the terrible winds of a violent storm, without rest. \n"
    print "         Virgil: To move on to the next circle, we must dodge these violent winds."
    print "         Virgil: Go forth, and dodge when you feel the winds... \n"
    for steps in range (0, 5):
        windblowing = random.randint(1,6)
        if windblowing < 0:
            print "The wind is blowing, violently!  What do you do?"
            windact = raw_input("> ")
            steps + 1
            if windact == "dodge":
                steps + 1
            else:
                print "I don't know what you mean."
                steps + 1
        elif windblowing > 0:
            print "The winds seemed to have died down.  You should take another step."
            windact2 = raw_input("> ")
            if windact2 == "step":
                print "You step carefully..."
                steps + 1
            else: 
                print "I don't know what you mean."
                steps + 1
        else:
            print "oops! something broke."
    if steps == 4:
        print "You made it!"
    return 'Gluttony'
```

If I run the larger piece of code that this is in, it runs it twice before returning "You made it!" when the player successfully "walks through."  How come?

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, you are calling this method twice... Please fix the indentation in your question.

Comment: `steps + 1` - this does *not* increase the number of steps so.. also, `steps` is already from the loop iterator (it will 'step itself' each loop) so it's confusing at best. In addition `windblowing < 0` is never true. The result is getting to "The winds seemed.." {input} for each of the 5 loops and is not 'repeating' so much as following the logic.

Comment: @user2864740 so, I don't need it in there?  Thanks.  But then what should I replace the if statement with?

Comment: The code should probably use `while True:` (or `while steps < 4:`) and then *actually* increment (or decrement to "go backwards") a `steps` variable (such as `steps = steps + 1`)  and put the `if steps == 4:` *inside* the loop (to end it, and/or use a better loop termination condition) and fix `windblowing` so that sometimes there is a different situation..

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @n1c9 if it looks better, `steps += 1` works as well, and that's probably what you wanted to write in the code.

Comment: You are correct, @knight ! Thanks.